# I get an internal server error whenever I attempt to submit an openCypher mutation with an embedded property element to AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencypher, neptune

AWS Neptune responds with an InternalServerError whenever I submit an openCypher mutation that contains an embedded property element such as:  `CREATE (t:test {prop1: '123'})`. A create followed by a SET works just fine: `CREATE (t:test) SET t.prop1 = '123'` . This isn't a huge deal with something like CREATE but it makes MERGE fairly useless since you can only MERGE on a given label (or labels). The documentation and related examples seem to suggest that this is supported (it's certainly valid in openCypher). The use case would be something like:  `MERGE (t:test {prop1: '123'}) ON CREATE <do something> ON MATCH <do something else>` . The following example is pulled directly from the AWS website as the way to do a cypher query in AWS Neptune openCypher:

```
You can write the same query in openCypher for Neptune as follows:
MATCH p=(a:airport {code: 'ANC'})-[r:route*1..3]->(z:airport {code: 'AUS'})
```

It clearly suggests that an embedded property element in the node/vertice is supported but every test I executed against the HTTP openCypher endpoint using and embedded property syntax failed with an InternalServerError. The same mutation with an outer SET statement worked fine. I'm using 1.3.0 version of the serverless AWS Neptune. This seems to be an issue for both queries and mutations. Doing a `MATCH (t:test) WHERE t.prop1='123' RETURN t` worked fine, but the example (as suggested above) `MATCH (t:test {prop1: '123}) RETURN t` resulted in an InternalServerError.

I tried both queries and mutations with embedded property elements and both scenarios are failing for me. It's hard to imagine this doesn't work, I'm assuming it's user error on my part, but I've been unable to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Amazon Neptune engine version are you using? I ran a test using the 1.3.0 level engine and  `CREATE (t:test {prop1: '123'})` worked fine. How are you submitting the query? I just used a Jupyter notebook, which sends the request to the HTTP endpoint.

Comment: I'm using the same version as you (1.3.0), I'm using the serverless version - are you as well? Currently calling the HTTP endpoint from a lambda function. I've been wondering if it had something to do with how I'm making the request but it seems odd that other cypher requests are processed correctly and only certain requests are failing. Basically I've been following examples I found / copied on how to sign/submit the requests to Neptune and, again, some requests are getting processed just fine. I'll go back and review my code doing the HTTP call.

Comment: Figured it out - just had to escape (encodeURI) the query string before submitting. At one point I had done that but had issues and had read another post that suggested not doing so. Thanks Kelvin for commenting.